# Some property of norm residue symbol

Tags: class-field-theory

On the last page of [this article](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN243919689_0154/PPN243919689_0154___LOG_0017.pdf), Artin and Hasse used some property of the norm residue symbol
$$\left(\frac{\lambda}{A}\right)_K = \left(\frac{\lambda}{n(A)}\right)_{k_\zeta}$$
(under *Beweis von Satz 3*) but I cannot seem to find any reference for this or any easy explanation. In the context of the paper, $k_\zeta = \mathbb{Q}_\ell(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $\ell^{\text{th}}$ root of unity with $\lambda = 1 - \zeta$ its uniformizer, $K$ is any field extension of $k_\zeta$, $A \equiv 1 \bmod \lambda$ in $K$, and $n$ denotes the relative norm $K/k_\zeta$. Is there an easy explanation and/or some generalization?

Comment: Hasse refers to his article http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002169487&physid=PHYS_0110 for the simple proof, which follows directly from the definition of the norm residue symbol.